# How to add path attributes (or labeled paths) in networkx

Tags: python, graph, networkx, graphml

I have a `path graph`, which is basically a single long path. To give a better Idea, consider the case that I need to represent 4 stanzas of a poem as a path.

```
Two roads diverged in a wood, and I
I took the one less traveled by,
And that has made all the difference
```

Now my path looks like

```
Two -> roads -> diverged -> ....... -> all -> the -> difference
```

Now, I need to add the information of the line (stanza) number in which the word is appearing in, along with the word number order in the line, i.e.

i.e. the word `Two` is stanza 1, word 1. `roads` is stanza 1, word 2. simialrly word `difference` is stanza 3 word 7. I need to add this information. I was wondering, if I can set a path attribute, such that I can define a path (or a sub-path/sub-graph), whihc I can label as stanza 1 and so on.

But I am not able to dind any such functionality in networks.

All I can find are two alternate ways:

1) Store the stanzaa and word number as two node attributes. 
2) Ad hyperedge, such that I can label the hyperedge.

But these does not give any additioanl advantage over the overhead that I have to take. Is there a more elegant solution.

I am looking for having a set of labeled paths (or sub-paths). If not in networkx, I am open to try any **python** graph libraries like `snap` or `igraph` etc.

### Current implementation

Currently, I am giving the stanza umber to each of the edge using the methods

`G.add_path([7,8,9,11],stanza=5)`.

Now I can access the same using `nx.get_edge_attributes(G,'stanza')`. Please let me know if anything more elegant is vailable